# Get Count of members in a AD Group using PrincipalSearcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, principalsearcher

Env : Visual Studio 2013, FrameWork 4.5, Telerik Controls, C#, WebForm application

Using : System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

I'm making a search tools so a user can search for a active directory group name in multiple forest/domain.

The search return a list of 1 or more group and I put that list in a RadGrid (Telerik). Each row of the grid is a AD Group. I would like to display an additional information that show the user how many(count?) members(users) there is in that group.

```
private List<AdGroup> GetListOfGroupAD(string domain, string name, string samAccountName)
    {
        try
        {
            GroupPrincipal qbeGroup;
            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
                qbeGroup.Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? name : "*";
                qbeGroup.SamAccountName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(samAccountName) ? samAccountName : "*";
                PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);
                ((DirectorySearcher)srch.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).PageSize = 500;

                List<AdGroup> listeGroupe = srch.FindAll()
                                      .OrderBy(x => x.SamAccountName)
                                      .Select(x => new AdGroup()
                                      {
                                          SamAccountName = x.SamAccountName,
                                          Description = x.Description,
                                          Domain = domain,
                                          NbMember = 0 //Can i Get a count of members in group here ?????
                                      })
                                      .ToList();
                return listeGroupe;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            writeToLog(ex.Message, 1);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeToLog(ex.Message, 1);
            return null;
        }
    }

public class AdGroup
    {
        public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public int NbMember { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you for the help

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to specify the type of the search result as `GroupPrincipal` using [`.OfType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) after the call to `FindAll()`, and then you can get the members of each group as a collection using the [`Members`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.members(v=vs.110).aspx) collection property or the [`GetMembers()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which has an optional boolean argument to specify if you need to search the group recursively for nested members. At that point, get the size of the collection.

```
List<AdGroup> listeGroupe = srch.FindAll()
    .OfType<GroupPrincipal>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.SamAccountName)
    .Select(x => new AdGroup()
    {
        SamAccountName = x.SamAccountName,
        Description = x.Description,
        Domain = domain,
        NbMember = x.Members.Count
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try your suggestion  but I get this Exception "While trying to resolve a cross-store reference, the target principal could not be found in the domain indicated by the principal's SID." : Is this indicate that a member of the group might not be part of the domain from the actual context ?

Comment: Yes, that error suggests that a member of one of your groups on your domain has an invalid SID.