# Active Directory: Get num of users/groups in a domain without loading all the users/groups?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I want to get number of users/groups in a domain without loading all the users/groups.

Is this possible? especially in c#?

Comment: This could probably help you for that : [Get Count of members in a AD Group using PrincipalSearcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089911/get-count-of-members-in-a-ad-group-using-principalsearcher)

Comment: This link above still loads all users before getting the count.

Comment: There's no way around internally or externally to count without enumerating a collection.  The concept of counting is to enumerate a collection.  For instance if I have a collection of students even doing Students.Count will go through all of them internally one way or other.

Another example is a C# DataSet RowCount.  Just asking it will take a certain amount of time if you have a lot of records.  Guess why ?

Comment: On another note, I saw people keeping RowCount and adding one when a student is added thus always having the count but this also imply that if you delete a student you have to decrease your RowCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really possible in AD. You need to query LDAP with an appropriate filter and count the results. There is a `numSubordinates` attribute that exists in some LDAP implementations which will tell you how many objects exist underneath a specific object, but AD does not support it. The closest you can get is [msDS-Approx-Immed-Subordinates](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/MsDS-Approx-Immed-Subordinates).

However, even if one of the above attributes were available, there's no way to make a distinction between the type of subordinate objects in the count. Unless you can guarantee that only users/groups reside under a specific structure in your directory and nothing else.